# pointer to arrays of struct

Tags: pointers, struct, member

```
struct a{
  double array[2][3];
};

struct b{
  double array[3][4];
};

void main(){
  a x = {{1,2,3,4,5,6}};
  b y = {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}};
}
```

I have two structs, inside which there are two dim arrays with different sizes. If I want to define only one function, which can deal with both `x` and `y` (one for each time), i.e., the function allows both `x.array` and `y.array` to be its argument. How can I define the input argument? I think I should use a pointer.... But `**x.array` seems not to work.

For example, I want to write a function `PrintArray` which can print the input array.

```
void PrintArray(  ){}
```

What should I input into the parenthesis? `double **` seems not work for me... (we can let dimension to be the PrintArray's argument as well, telling them its 2*3 array)

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that takes three parameters: a pointer, the number of rows, and the number of columns. When you call the function, reduce the array to a pointer.

```
void PrintArray(const double *a, int rows, int cols) {
    int r, c;
    for (r = 0;  r < rows;  ++r) {
        for (c = 0;  c < cols;  ++c) {
            printf("%3.1f ", a[r * cols + c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(){
    struct a x = {{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}};
    struct b y = {{{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}}};
    PrintArray(&x.array[0][0], 2, 3);
    PrintArray(&y.array[0][0], 3, 4);
    return 0;
}
```